# how to search by id in jdbc

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I use in my code jdbc
wrote the following code to search id:

```
public Item findById(String id) {
        Item result = null;

        String s = "SELECT id, key, name, creat, description FROM trackersql WHERE id = :id";

        try (Connection connection = init()) {
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(s);

            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

            while(resultSet.next()) {
                Item item = new Item();

                statement.setString(1, id);
                statement.setString(2, item.getKey());
                statement.setString(3, item.getName());
                statement.setLong(4, item.getCreat());
                statement.setString(5, item.getDescription());
                statement.executeUpdate();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

doing my code check this way:

```
try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.postgresql.Driver());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        TrackerSQL trackerSQL = new TrackerSQL();
        Item item1 = new Item("1", "1", "test1", 1, "test1");

        trackerSQL.init();

        System.out.println(trackerSQL.findById(item1.getId()));
```

but I get the following error:

> ERROR: syntax error (approximate position: ":") Position: 69 at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)     at ru.job4j.trackersql2.TrackerSQL.findById(TrackerSQL.java:104)    at
>   ru.job4j.trackersql2.TrackerSQL.main(TrackerSQL.java:188) null

what is my mistake?

Comment: JDBC does not know named parameter. replce `:id` with `?`. Also you never bind the parameter

Comment: Thanks. But I get the following error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The value for parameter 1 is not specified .org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.checkAllParametersSet(SimpleParameterList.java:178)
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:246)
null

Comment: that's what i mean with *Also you never bind the parameter*

Comment: How do I bind a parameter?

Comment: See my answer. BTW is your id an string or an integer?

Answer (score 0):

JDBC does not know named parameter. repalce `:id` with `?`. Also you never bind the parameter

```
String s = "SELECT id, key, name, creat, description FROM trackersql WHERE id = ?";
try (Connection connection = init()) {
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(s);
    statement.setString(1,id)
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
```

There is an other erro in your code:

```
            statement.setString(1, id);
            statement.setString(2, item.getKey());
            statement.setString(3, item.getName());
            statement.setLong(4, item.getCreat());
            statement.setString(5, item.getDescription());
            statement.executeUpdate();
```

must be

```
          Item item = new Item();

            item.setId(1, rs.getString(1));
            item.setKey(2, rs.getString(2));
          return item;
```

Comment: I did this way:  public Item findById(String id) {
        Item result = null;

        String s = "SELECT * FROM trackersql WHERE id = ?";

        try (Connection connection = init()) {
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(s);
            statement.setString(1, id);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }  and get as a result null

Comment: Do you mean `resultSet` is null?

Comment: that way I will also get null. I have a method type - Item.

Comment: @Mr.Bin Sorry can't get you

Comment: Check the datatype, if `key` is an integer datatype you have to use getInt(). BTW: Be care full with column names like *key* that are reserved words in sql https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words

Comment: I get this error:ERROR: statement does not exist: integer = character varying
   Hint: An operator with the given name and argument types was not found. Perhaps you should add explicit type conversions.
   Position: 67

Comment: Please check the datatype in your db and take the correct get... method from resultset and the correct index!